# Can contentOwners use youtube analytics API to find ContentType(uploaderType) of a video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics

Using CMS account we can download raw data files from youtube(https://cms.youtube.com/cyc_download_reports).
This csv does have information whether a video was Partner-provided or UGC. 
The corresponding closest match from Youtube Analytics API I believe is using the uploaderType
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=contentOwner%3D%3DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&start-date=2013-06-17&end-date=2013-06-21&metrics=views&filters=uploaderType%3D%3Dself&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

But this is at a contentOwner Level rather than at video level.Kindly let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: I don't understand what you want help with. Can you be more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not missing anything. You can run a content-owner YouTube Analytics API report and use the `uploaderType` as a filter, to find stats about all the videos underneath that content owner that have a specific uploader type value. You can't request `uploaderType` as a dimension in a request with a `video==` or `channel==` filter, though.

The matrix of supported parameters is at https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/content_owner_reports#Reports